# Uploading a file from a bootstrap modal using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to upload a file to a server from a bootstrap modal window, using ajax.

The modal html is

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div>
<form class="form" role="form" id="attachform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
$("#attachform").on('submit',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var postData = new FormData($("#attachform")[0]);
console.log(postData);
$.ajax({
   url: "attachment.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: data,
   processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
   contentType: false
   }).done(function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
    $('#myAttachModal').modal('hide');
            });
    });
});
```

The PHP server code

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

I am not seeing anything in the $_FILES array when I run this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data value in your Ajax post to postData. postData contains the form data.

Change this section

`data: data,`

To

`data: postData,//this contains the form data`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the  data : data kew value inside the

```
$.ajax({
  data : postData,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "attachment.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: postData,
   processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
   contentType: false
   }).done(function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
    $('#myAttachModal').modal('hide');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain that you changed the variable's name that is passed into the `data` property to the variable that gets the form's data (`postData`). It's hard to tell that you just did not copy paste his code.